# Initialize an array in a React Native useState

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo

I'm working on a react native application.

I get the result of an SQL query like this:

```
const [ food, setFood ] = useState([]);

const load_food = async () => {
    db.listProduct().then(row => setFood(row))
};
useFocusEffect( () => { load_food(food) }, [ food ] );
```

If I make a log like this:

```
console.log(food[i].PRODUCTNAME)
```

I get the name of my ingredient:

```
"Orange Juice"
```

Later I want to create a list from the variable food

```
const [listData, setListData] = useState(
    Array(10)
        .fill('')
        .map((_, i) => ({ key: `${i}`, text: `Product name: ${food[i].PRODUCTNAME}`}))
);
```

But I have the following error:

*undefined is not an object (evaluating 'food[i].PRODUCTNAME')*

I imagine it's a synchronization issue. But I don't know how to solve it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're mainly correct, it could be a sync problem, and you can use some techniques to avoid it, `useEffect` is one of them

```
const [listData, setListData] = useState([]);
useEffect(()=> {
  setListData(
    Array(10)
        .fill('')
        .map((_, i) => ({ key: `${i}`, text: `Product name: ${food[i].PRODUCTNAME}`}))
  )
}, [food]);
```

This will only set `listData` state when `food` is updated, but also you will have to check `food` has at least 10 items or you will get undefined again

Comment: It seems to work, thank you ! i set the array size to 'food.length'  I shouldn't have an error in this case